# Extensions/Plugins for Sublime Text for Non-Coding Purposes

Tags: sublimetext2

Probably a strange place to ask this, but, I figured there's no better one. I've been using Sublimetext for all of my coding/programming needs for a while and have just gotten incredibly used to it. I hate switching to openoffice/ms word/etc. for non code documents and losing the keymapping and great features. I was just wondering if anyone knows of any plugins that make everyday word processing work a little bit more palatable and formatted.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could try learning LaTeX, though that's quite an undertaking in my opinion. You could then use something like [LaTeXTools](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools).

For general note taking, I personally just turn on word wrap to something reasonable and turn spellcheck on. I then use Markdown like symbols  to denote list, headers, etc. Only Markdown like because I haven't taken the time to actually remember all the Markdown specific things.

"Non-coding purposes" is kind of broad, so I hope one of those two things mentioned will help.